# How to set sunspot solr data_path different from solr_home?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sunspot-rails

I have tried:

```
#sunspot.yml
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8982
    data_path: /solr_index
  auto_commit_after_request: false
```

My solr_home is at /project/testapp/solr. I manually created /solr_index dir. Whenever I start up my solr server, it creates a "data" dir under /project/testapp/solr instead of using the data_path specified in my sunspot.yml

Reference:

- https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/sunspot_rails/lib/sunspot/rails/configuration.rb
- http://sunspot.github.io/docs/Sunspot/Rails/Configuration.html

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue, it's `config/sunspot.yml` and you're starting solr with `rake:sunspot:run` or something similar, right?

Comment: I start solr with "bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start". To reproduce the issue: if I delete the default solr home's data dir, and then start solr, it recreates the default solr home's data dir instead of using the custom data path.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm doing, but I get expected output i.e. `index` in my `data_path` and `solr/conf` under `solr_home` (or in app root if not provided).

Comment: hmm...could be the gem version. I am using sunspot_rails -v 1.2.1 and I cannot upgrade right now. What version are you using?

Comment: Still can't reproduce that issue, can you share your Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

Your solution of a symbolic link is the best. Should probably be done by Capistrano during your deploy.

However you can specify a custom data dir for sunspot / solr:

Check your `RAILS_ROOT/solr/conf/solrconfig.xml` there should be something like:

```
  <dataDir>${solr.data.dir:./solr/data}</dataDir>
```

You should be able to change it :) Or remove/comment-out to use your `__current_solr_core_home_dir__/data`.

Answer (score 1):

In sunspot_solr 2.2.7 and Rails 4 + ,

the corresponding options are

1. path
2. solr_home

path: Is the url where the request to solr server goes.

solr_home: Here you can customize the solr to create index data files in different directory than default solr directory (Rails.root/solr)

A sample sunspot.yml file

```
production:
 solr:
   hostname: localhost
   port: 8983
   log_level: WARNING
   solr_home: /your/custom/path/ # /Users/abhi/solr_files
   path: /solr/production
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see data_path as an option in those config references. I only see a method named data_path below in the code. There is only path and solr_home as options in the config examples. Are you trying to separate the location of your indexed data from your solr config?

Comment: yes, I am trying to separate location of the solr indexed data from the default solr home path

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving my solr "data" dir to some custom path and then create a symbolic link solr/data that points to the custom path:

```
mv /path/to/solr/data /my/custom/solr/data/path
ln -s /my/custom/solr/data/path /path/to/solr/data
```